# Coding a COUNT in a VIEW in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I am stuck in a programming problem in Oracle, that I am trying to solve. I am suppose to create a View that will give me the Number of unreserved/Available seats on FBN001 ON 27TH October 2016

This is the Flight Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Flight(
  Flight_ID VARCHAR(25),
  Route_ID VARCHAR(25),
  Airplane_ID VARCHAR(10),
  Departure_Time DATE,
  Arrival_Time DATE,
    CONSTRAINT FlightIDPK PRIMARY KEY(Flight_ID),
    CONSTRAINT RouteIDFK FOREIGN KEY(Route_ID) REFERENCES Route(Route_ID),
    CONSTRAINT AirplaneIDFK FOREIGN KEY(Airplane_ID) REFERENCES Airplane(Airplane_ID));
```

This is the Airplane Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Airplane(
  Airplane_ID VARCHAR(10),
  Capacity NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
  Model VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT AirplaneIDPK PRIMARY KEY(Airplane_ID));
```

This is the Booking Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Booking(
  Booking_ID NUMBER(10),
  Flight_ID VARCHAR(25),
  Customer_ID NUMBER(10),
  Payment_Method VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  CreditCard_Details NUMBER(18),
    CONSTRAINT BookingIDPK PRIMARY KEY(Booking_ID),
    CONSTRAINT FlightIDFK FOREIGN KEY(Flight_ID) REFERENCES Flight(Flight_ID),
    CONSTRAINT CustomerIDFK FOREIGN KEY(Customer_ID) REFERENCES Customer(Customer_ID));
```

I thought i would use the COUNT function to count the Bookings

```
CREATE VIEW ViewB AS(
SELECT Flight.Route_ID, Flight.Departure_Time, Airplane.Capacity, COUNT(Flight_ID) AS NumberOfBooking
FROM Flight, Airplane, Booking
WHERE Flight.Airplane_ID = Airplane.Airplane_ID
AND Flight.Route_ID = 'FBN001'
GROUP BY Flight.Route_ID, Airplane.Capacity);
```

But that did not work,

It is giving me the Error

Error report -

SQL Error: ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined

918. 00000 -  "column ambiguously defined"

*Cause:

*Action:

What could be the solution?
Thank you

Comment: what you mean doesnt work? show us the error or the wrong result. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't add a statement to properly join the booking table:

```
CREATE VIEW ViewB AS(
SELECT Flight.Route_ID, Flight.Departure_Time, Airplane.Capacity,     COUNT(Flight_ID) AS NumberOfBooking
FROM Flight, Airplane, Booking
WHERE Flight.Airplane_ID = Airplane.Airplane_ID
AND Flight.Flight_ID=Booking.Flight_ID
AND Flight.Route_ID = 'FBN001'
GROUP BY Flight.Route_ID, Airplane.Capacity);
```

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: There is not statement to join the booking table. You have this:

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally submitted that. Anyway, you have Flight.Airplane_ID = Airplane.Airplane_ID to join the Flight and Airplane tables but nothing to join the Booking table to either one of those tables. So I added Flight.Flight_ID=Booking.Flight_ID

Comment: Oh, I just noticed the ambiguously defined error now. Yeah, that's referring  to your COUNT(Flight_ID) it should have the table name like COUNT(FLIGHT.Flight_ID).

Comment: But you still need to properly join that table or you will get the wrong answer even though it will run.

Comment: i did what you suggested and now im getting the error SQL Error: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"                             `code` (CREATE VIEW ViewB AS(
SELECT Flight.Route_ID, Flight.Departure_Time, Airplane.Capacity, COUNT(Booking.Flight_ID) AS NumberOfBooking
FROM Flight, Airplane, Booking
WHERE Flight.Airplane_ID = Airplane.Airplane_ID
AND Flight.Flight_ID =  Booking.Flight_ID
AND Flight.Route_ID = 'FBN001'
GROUP BY Flight.Route_ID, Airplane.Capacity);)

Comment: Yes, you need to add Flight.Departure_Time to the group by clause. Anything not in an aggregate function has to be part of the group by clause.

Comment: is there a way to subtract the Capacity and the NumberOfBooking, to show the seats left?

Comment: If I understand these relationships correctly: airplane.capacity - count(booking.Booking_ID) .

Comment: will it work if i added it directly to the same view?

Comment: Sure  <br/> CREATE VIEW ViewB AS(
SELECT Flight.Route_ID, 
Flight.Departure_Time, 
Airplane.Capacity,
COUNT(Flight_ID) AS NumberOfBooking,
airplane.capacity - count(booking.Booking_ID) seats_left
FROM Flight, Airplane, Booking
WHERE Flight.Airplane_ID = Airplane.Airplane_ID
AND Flight.Flight_ID=Booking.Flight_ID
AND Flight.Route_ID = 'FBN001'
GROUP BY Flight.Route_ID, Airplane.Capacity);

Comment: Logically I don't think the line COUNT(Flight_ID) AS NumberOfBooking, is what you are looking for. The way I understand this it will give you the number of flights, not the number of seats.

Comment: Thank you So Much!!

Comment: No, it was correct, it gave me the number of seats, which is 4, because i have 6 flights

Comment: No problem. This was my first answered question!